# Make Android device act as an iBeacon

Tags: android, cordova-plugins, altbeacon, beacon

I'm looking for plugins in cordova, to make an app in ionic that acts as Beacon. 
My app now can view the beacons and also connect to them but I didn't found a plugin to make my smartphone a beacon. Is that a way to crat that plugin? Maybe in cordova ? I want it for android, any suggestion? I googled but nothing. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44096759/phone-act-as-beacon